# No se estan guardando los datos en mi lista

Tags: python

tengo un problemilla haciendo un trabajo para la universidad, me queda poco plazo para entregarlo, tengo que hacer una aplicacion donde permita ingresar el nombre de N trabajadores, sus horas trabajadas y su sueldo, luego calcular un bono dependiendo de sus horas trabajadas y imprimir los datos de los trabajadores, con su sueldo y su bono, quiero meter todos esos datos a una lista y luego imprimir la lista, pero los datos no se estan guardando en esta.

Soy nuevo en la programacion, por favor hacer las explicaciones lo mas simple posibles, y si me pueden ayudar con el codigo aun mejor, muchisimas gracias al que me ayude.

archivo con las clases

```
class Trabajador:
    nombre=""
    horas = 0
    sueldo = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.horas=horas
        self.sueldo=sueldo
        pass

class Main:

    lista_trabajadores=[]

    def __init__(self,lista_trabajadores):
        self.lista_trabajadores=lista_trabajadores

    def ingreso_trabajador():
        Trabajador.nombre=input("Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ")
        while True:
            try:
                Trabajador.horas = float(input("Ingrese las horas trabajadas: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Ingrese un valor numerico, intentelo nuevamente")
        while True:
            try:
                Trabajador.sueldo = int(input("Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: "))
                if (Trabajador.horas < 30):
                    bono=(Trabajador.sueldo * 15 / 100) 
                    print(bono)
                    break
                elif (Trabajador.horas >= 30 and Trabajador.horas < 40):
                    bono=(Trabajador.sueldo * 25 / 100)
                    print(bono)
                    break
                elif (Trabajador.horas >= 40):
                    bono=(Trabajador.sueldo * 35 / 100)
                    print (bono)
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print("Ingrese un valor numerico entero, intentelo nuevamente")
                T=trabajador(Trabajador.nombre, Trabajador.horas, Trabajador.sueldo)
                lista_trabajadores.append(T)
                opc=input("Desea ingresar otro trabajador? si/no")
                if opc=="no":
                    break


def menu():
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print("MENU PRINCIPAL")
    print("1- Ingresar Trabajador")
    print("2- Mostrar los datos de los trabajadores")
    print("0- Salir")
```

Archivo con el programa

```
from Trabajador1 import *

menu()
while True:
    try:
        opc = int(input("Ingrese su opcion: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar una opcion valida, intentelo nuevamente")


while opc!=0:
    if opc == 1:
        while True:
            Main.ingreso_trabajador()
            opc=input("Desea ingresar otro trabajador? si/no : ")
            if opc == "no":
                break
    
    if opc==2:
        print(Main.lista_trabajadores) #aca solamente estoy dejando el print para ver si los 
                                       #datos se estan guardando
    
    

    menu()
    opc = int(input(">"))
```

Comment: La razón directa es porque no le estás enviando los datos a `self.lista_trabajadores`. Por otro lado, tienes varios errores en el concepto de la POO. ¿Es necesario trabajar con clases? Lo pregunto porque nunca creas una instancia, desaprovechando el poder de la POO. Si no son necesarias las clases, podrías hacer este problema usando solo funciones.

Comment: Estoy usando las clases porque parte del requerimiento del ejercicio dado por el profesor, por otro lado, como le envio los datos a `self.lista_trabajadores`? crei que le estaba enviando los datos en la parte de   ```T=trabajador(Trabajador.nombre, Trabajador.horas, Trabajador.sueldo) lista_trabajadores.append(T) ``` pero supongo que no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Las variable nombre, horas y sueldo que están antes del __init__ son varíables de la clase, es decir, son comunes a todas las instancias que crees de la clase Trabajador. 

Por otro lado, en el __init__ las variables, nombre, horas y sueldo son varíables de instancia. Por lo tanto, son diferentes a las variables de arriba así tengan el mismo nombre:
```

Trabajador.nombre='Juan'

```
Aquí afectas a la variable nombre de la clase. Si luego haces Trabajador.nombre='Pedro', entonces, estarías reemplazando 'Juan' por 'Pedro' ya que utilizas variables de clase que son únicas para todas las instancias.
```

oTrabajador=Trabajador()
oTrabajador.nombre='Juan'
l.append(oTrabajador)
oTrabajador.nombre='Pedro'
l.append(oTrabajador)

```
Aquí creas una instancia de Trabajador en oTrabajador y asignas el nombre. Aquí la variable nombre que se afecta es la que está dentro del __init__.
Luego creas otra instancia de Trabajador para Pedro y agregas a la lista. La variable `l` tendrá dos elementos una para 'Juan' y otra para `Pedro`. Si hubiera agregado a la lista utilizando el nombre de la clase `l` tendría el mismo dato para todos los elementos.


Olvidé que el `__init__` si bien asignas las variables de clase a las variables de instancia el efecto es el mismo porque todas las instancias harán referencia a las variables de clase. En tu __init__ agrégale parámetros de nombre,horas y sueldo y asigna a esas a la instancia. Luego haces oTrabajador=Trabajador('Juan`,1,19).

Al margen que el __init__ nunca se ejecuta porque no creas una instancia.


**EDICIÓN:*** Ajustes mínimos para superar problema

1. La clase **Trabajador**, aunque mas que una clase es una estructura, tiene un problema en su definición. 

   class Trabajador:
      # Las variables que se definen a este
      # nivel son propios de clase y aplican a todos los objetos,
      # por lo tanto, son los mismos para cualquier instancia de la clase

 
      # Generalmente el nombre, las horas y el sueldo aplican a cada objeto 
      # que se crea a partir de esta clase. 
      # Cada trabajador tiene un nombre, unas horas trabajadas y un sueldo  que
      # lo distingue de otro de su clase, por lo tanto, elimina estas lineas.
   

      #nombre=""
      #horas=0
      #sueldo=0


       # El metodo __init__ tiene la función de crear una instancia o un objeto 
       # de la clase y es el lugar adecuado para inicializar un objeto. Como tu 
       # clase es una estructura de datos. En este metodo puedes pasarle los atributos 
       # del trabajador, por lo tanto, le agregamos tres parametros: nombre, horas y sueldo.
       # El paramentro "self" es requerido por python y no entraré a detallarlo.


       def __init__(self,nombre="",horas=0,sueldo=0):
           # Aqui recién vamos a declarar las propiedades del objeto, es decir, el nombre, horas y sueldo a estas
           # debes referenciarlas con ´self.` Realmente estas variables debería se ocultas 
           # al exterior y definir metodos getter y setter
           # Este metodo se ejcuta cuando se hace: oTrab=Trabajador("Juan",1,2) 
           # Las variables aqui no deben estar definidas anteriormente. Al parecer has pensado que deberian ser definidas antes de usuarse pero aqui es donde realmente se definen las variables de objetos: anteponiendo self.
           self.nombre = nombre
           self.horas = horas
           self.sueldo = sueldo
```

Hasta aqui es todo lo que necesitas.  En la clase **main** agrega al metodo de Ingreso una linea: trabajador=Trabajador() y cambias todas las referencia de Trabajor por trabajador.

Comment: Disculpa, donde me dijiste que le agregue en mi init los paramentros, te refieres an init de el Main?